# set a timeoutfunction in wordpress jquery file

Tags: jquery, wordpress, settimeout

I have a piece of javascript in a template which select an option from a select dropdown and causes a .change effect when loading a page.

This works fine. However instead of having this in the template file directly i want to add the funciton in a javascript file and call it in my functions when i am on a certain page.

I have trouble setting up the timeout element of my function for a .change to happen.

Below is my working script directly in the template file

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("select").val('56');

window.setTimeout(function() { jQuery('.level-1').change();}, 0.5);

});
</script>
```

---

So now my rewritten function in a file.js

This is my functions file to call the js file

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'load_js');
function load_js() {

  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core3', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/jquery331.js');


  if (is_page ('395')) { 
 wp_enqueue_script( 'scriptfile1', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/page395.js');
  }

}
```

and this is my page395.js file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("select").val('56');

    window.setTimeout(function() { 
       jQuery('.level-1').change();}, 0.5);


});
```

I dont know how to rewrite the windpws.setTimeout function. The one above is not working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have not used settimeout function properly. Try below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("select").val('56');

    setTimeout(function() { 
       jQuery('.level-1').change();
    }, 1000); //here 1000 means 1 second

});
```

Comment: @Missblues if you have tried this one and get helpful than make it as correct answer